# SimpleDateFormat throws parse Exception for +0100

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I am trying with two sets of date with date format :

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

It works fine for the Date : Fri, 26 Aug 2016 13:55:34 +0000

Not for the Date : Tue, 06 Sep 2016 11:57:14 +0100

Throws exception for the +0100 date.

```
 Unparseable date: "Tue, 06 Sep 2016 11:57:14 +0100" (at offset 0)
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH); Still throwing the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails at `offset 0`, which means that the problem is not related to the **timezone** but to the **day in letters**.

You should set the `Locale` of your `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date d1 = format.parse("Fri, 26 Aug 2016 13:55:34 +0000");
    Date d2 = format.parse("Tue, 06 Sep 2016 11:57:14 +0100");
```

Works without any problem.

If you also need to retrieve the timezone, you will also have to add `z` to your pattern:

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Upvoted as I've stolen your locale point and need to clear my conscience.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
Still not working.

Comment: Thanks.. It is working.. the string I am passing has some extra whitespaces that caused the problem

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
```

Note the `z` for the time zone.

The parser ignores the zero (`+0000`) case if `z` is not supplied, but **not** a non-zero (`+0100`) case. The `lenient` property controls this behaviour (Acknowledge @Marko Topolnik).

Since you're using English week names, you ought to use the two-argument constructor to `SimpleDateFormat`, passing `Locale.ENGLISH` as the second parameter.

Comment: Still it throwing the same error. I am trying this in android

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
Still no luck